# Unable to access hosted .NET web application over internet

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment

We have a .NET application that we hosted in our Server (windows). We are able to browse the same locally on the server IE but it is not available over the internet. Infrastructure team that set up the server ensured-
* Website has been DNS registered.
*All required ports are open.

What else could be the issue for the website not being available over internet?
What else can we check in terms of configurations?

Comment: what error do you get? if you trying to access using DNS, can you try using IP address? what error do you get then? Does you site name resolve when typing "ping domain.com"?

Comment: I just get Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

Comment: I asked the Infrastructure team and yes the site name is being resolved correctly..what else..should I check..

Comment: did you try accessing it using IP? do you get any response when you do "ping ip_address" in command prompt? There are so many things that can be wrong it is too much to check, so it needs to be done one by one. When accessing locally, do you use http://localhost or http://172.0.0.1? Do both work?